# Do assumptions for estimators affect population parameters?

Tags: regression, model, weighted-regression, parameterization

**TL;DR**: Specifying a model (a collection of restrictions over a sample space) specifies the model parameters. Specifying an estimation procedure adds additional number of restrictions (assumptions?). Do the parameters being estimated remain invariant given this additional number of restrictions?

I just read a really good exposition that helps interpret WLS coefficients:

[Interpret regression coefficients after WLS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41563/interpret-regression-coefficients-after-wls)

(Top answer, by Fg)

One of the lines really struck me with something I've been trying to understand for a while:

> The key is in the way you say it -- OLS and WLS estimates of *the* model
>   parameters, implying one set of population parameters being estimated
>   by both estimators.

Fg's answer implied that model parameters are invariant to the estimation technique being used. Surely, however, the population error covariance matrix ($\Sigma$) is considered a member of the parameter space themselves, and the OLS and WLS specify different outcomes for these parameters. Or are we only interested in getting accurate estimates for $\beta$, the true values of which remain invariant?

To illustrate: given my data, I specify a linear regression model:

$$Y \sim N(\beta^T X, \Sigma )$$

So the parameters I want to find are $(\beta,\Sigma)$.
According to Fg the parameters $\beta$ are identical whether or not I use OLS or WLS estimation.

But OLS adds an additional assumption that the covariance matrix follows a certain pattern:

$$\Sigma=\sigma*I$$

Which the WLS procedure does not impose. Therefore the population parameter $\Sigma$ being estimated in both examples is likely to be different. How does this couch with Fg's statement?

*Note*: One could easily extend the above argument to state that the specification of *any* model causes this confusion, for example if you specified a Poisson regression, the values being estimated change (necessarily). That happens to be the broader issue I've been struggling with. How do the subjective assumptions that define the model/estimation procedure lead to objective targets for parameter estimation? Where does model specification/restriction end and assumptions for estimation begin?