# Interpreting the robust linear regression

Tags: interpretation, robust

> Is the way that we interpret the coefficients of a robust linear
>   regression (rlm function in R) is the same as the OLS regression? Can I interpret the
>   coefficient of a robust regression (forexample) in the following way:
>
> Suppose that Age is a predictor and Systolic is a dependent variable, so we can say that with every increase of one year in age,
>   the systolic BP (on the average) increases by 1.051 (95% CI 0.752 to
>   1.350) units

Answer (score 1):

In robust linear regression, the model you are estimating is still a linear regression, and the coefficients of the predictor variables in the model still has the same interpretation, they are simply partial derivatives. So the answer is, **YES**, the interpretation is the same.

For more detailed answers to  a similar question, see [Interpret regression coefficients after WLS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41563/interpret-regression-coefficients-after-wls)